# logging problem while creating a firebase admin sdk project in java gradle project

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, slf4j, firebase-admin

i am creating a firebase admin-sdk project in java gradle project in intellij. The code for the project is as follows.

[image]

i have added the necessary dependencies as follows.

[image]

In that dependencies it also contains slf4j-api.jar as shown below.

[image]

Even after that there is a logging problem when the project is run as below
and cannot connect to the firebase. The output is as below.

[image]

how to add binding to the class path so that the project may work properly in the gradle project.

[related link](https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder)

Answer (score 1):

Did you visit the link in the error message (https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder)? It explains exactly what's going on, and how to fix it. For more details you can also refer to [this article](https://medium.com/@hiranya911/logging-in-java-libraries-for-firebase-and-google-cloud-platform-f8742493b73f).